# Transform CSV Column Values into Single Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark-2.0

My data in CSV is like this(Expected Image): 
[Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK9jH.png)

And I want to convert this Data into:
[Expected Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uULqq.png)
(**hivetablename.hivecolumnname = dbtablename.dbtablecolumn**)

By joining the multiple Row values into a Single row value like above.

Please note that 'AND' is a Literal between the condition to be built, which would appear until the second last record.

Once the Last Record is reached, Only the condition would appear(xx=yy)

I wish the result to be in SCALA SPARK.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Im a learner so couldnt go much further. Heres what Ive been able to achieve  
val dfconf= spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file:///conf.csv").alias("conf"); 
dfconf.show(10, false)

val newDF1 = dfconf.withColumn("Y",lit("1")) 
val newDF2 = newDF1.withColumn("Z",lit(","))
val newDF3 = newDF2.withColumn("comb",concat($"hivetablename",lit("."),$"hivetablecolumn",lit("="),$"dbtablename",lit("."),$"dbtablecolumn"))
newDF3.show()
val newDF4 = newDF3.groupBy("Y").agg(collect_set("z").as("combined"))